# Webkit browsers showing blue text as slightly purple

Tags: css, google-chrome

I can't find any info on this issue in Google, because every result is about the default purple `a:visited` color. That is NOT the issue here. The issue is with Chrome's default anti-aliasing, on some systems blue text shows up as blueish-purple. If I change the anti-aliasing to `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased` it keeps the correct color, but then the fonts are radically different between Chrome and Firefox. The blue color I'm using is the client's color, so it cannot change to purple like this. I'm hoping somebody has a fix for this.

Here are screenshots from tests I've done:

[image: Google Chrome blue text showing as purple on different systems]

EDIT: Just to clarify, this has nothing to do with the default `a:visited` link color. My blue color is being inherited, but Chrome's anti-aliasing is causing the text to appear purple. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/yvjjxfqt/

Comment: Post all the the css properties applied on the text.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. check the edit. The color is the only CSS style. Like I mentioned before, this is not a color inheritance issue. From what I can see it's an anti-aliasing issue. The jsfiddle I posted has the same purple text problem.

Comment: Stupid review audit ate my comment... anyway, on Windows, this looks like an interaction with ClearType, as the horizontal lines in the example have the correct colour on both browsers, while the vertical lines are strongly sub-pixel-anti-aliased on Chrome but only slightly so on Firefox. (Also if you turn ClearType off then Firefox also disables antialiasing whereas Chrome does not.)

Comment: @Neil this also happens in OSX though, but only on non-retina screens. Maybe Chrome uses their own type renderer?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It gets solved (at least in my system) setting a transform in the element

```css
a {
    color: #1967b1;
    display: block;
}

a:nth-child(2) {
    transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is a link</a>
<a href="#">This is a link</a>
```

I guess that the rendering in the gpu doesn't have this problem

This is how it looks in my system

[image: zoomed display]

Another way to solve it seems to be using opacity

```css
a {
    color: #1967b1;
    opacity: 0.99;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is a link</a>
```

Comment: Any reason why you went with the rotate rather than transform3d  (the more common trick for forcing hardware acceleration)? Just curious.

Comment: Take note that this only works if the element has a block type display setting. This solution does not work when the element is set to `display:inline;`.

Comment: @vals Thanks! That did it!

Comment: Happy that it helped !

Comment: @IMI You are right. I have added another solution that doesn't have this problem

Comment: @vals - Nice opacity solution. Since this seems to be a webkit issue, you can probably just use the prefixed `-webkit-opacity` property.